# Nginx configuration to add www neglects request uri

Tags: linux, http, redirect, nginx

Following is the configuration I used in nginx.conf to rewrite all non www.example.com requests to add www to it.

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  example.co.uk;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.example.co.uk$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.co.uk;
  root /home/ubuntu/apps/example/current/public;
  ...
}
```

Expectation:
http://example.com/image4.png
should do permanent redirect to http://www.example.com/image4.png

but what happens is when http://example.com/image4.png requested, it redirects to http://example.com.

Where I am doing mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what's wrong, but probably `$1` is empty, here's a better way to do it.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name  example.co.uk;
    return 301 http://www.example.co.uk$request_uri;
}
```